# Can a Local Notification triggering be detected without tapping on the notification?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

My app starts a timer when the local notification based on date is triggered using `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate::didReceive` delegate.

But what if the app is already opened when notification is triggered, I want my timer to start automatically at that point, without tapping on the notification.

Is this possible ?

e.g:

I want to set a notification for 3 pm, at that point start a 30 min timer (this should start at exactly 3 pm), that will expire at 3:30 pm.
What if the user taps on notification 10 mins later, at 3:10 pm...the timer will expire at 3:40. 
That is why I want to start the timer when notification is triggered, not when the user taps on it.

Comment: Method userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:) will be called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app. Reference : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter

Comment: @Hooda: can you provide this as an answer so I can accepted ? Thanks.

Comment: Done. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:) will be called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.

Source : [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for using your timer concept

```
application:didReceiveLocalNotification:
```

But yes when your app is in background state, and if local notification come, you won't receive any method call.

Comment: What do u mean ? that is called when you tap on the notification, right ?

Comment: Yes, As far as I know, when your app is in background state, and if local notification come, you won't receive any method call.

Comment: And when your app is in foreground this method will be called automatically